# Installing Python client and server subpackages under common superpackage using distutils

Tags: python, distutils

I have a Python project which follows a client-server architecture. It is natural to distribute it as two different projects, myproject-server and myproject-client.  I want to be able to independently install each of them using setup.py and distutils, but so that they appear as subpackages under a common superpackage.  So that either of the following commands works properly, independently of the other:

```
import myproject.server
import myproject.client
```

Is there a way to write distutils/setup.py to do this?  Thanks.

P.S. Examples of projects which do a similar thing would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If i am reading your requirement correctly.
Passing packages = ["x", "x.client", "x.server"] in distutils.core.setup() should do it.

Comment: But the client and server are in different source distributions, such as `client.tar.gz` and `server.tar.gz`. So there would have to be something like `packages = ["x", "x.client"]` in the client's `setup.py` and `packages = ["x", "x.server"]` in the server's `setup.py`. This kind of works, but it feels wrong because the second package which gets installed will overwrite files from the first. For example, there is no way to install a `x/__init__.py` file in the top-level superpackage in a clean way. Any ideas?